Pixelwise least square in Python
I have a non-linear forward model which computes a gray scale image for a per-pixel parameter w. I am also able to invert the model using scipys optimize functions. The only problem I am having currently is the size of the image is making this solution really slow... Like 7% of the pixels have been calculated in 40 minutes slow. I am looping over all pixels with a for-loop and applying the model pixelwise. I have tried the least_squares, leastsq, and root functions, but all of them are quite slow. I also implemented the derivative values, since I heard it could be faster by providing the jacobian matrix, but to no avail.
I thought the leastsq could be the solution, since it has the following statement in the description:
x = arg min(sum(func(y)**2,axis=0))
         y

If I reshaped my image as 1xn, it should minimize along the axis=0. But somehow I end up with an array of size 2 as my input argument y, and I wasn't able to debug it.
I am especially looking at least square optimizations, since in the future, I would like to provide multiple images, which should be generated by the same parameter w (with other arguments varying).
Are there any libraries besides scipy, which would provide a more elegant approach to this problem?
I was also planning on trying a numba implementation of the root function, but it has its own problems. Or to use Googles JAX implementation of LM, but I have no real experience with JAX so far...
EDIT 1
Here is a small example of my problem:
Lets say I have a model defines as f(n) = a*n**2 + b*n + c, where f(n) is the image value per pixel n. For different triplets (a,b,c) I can generate images I=f(n). Now I have a set of images given I1, I2, ... with different parameters (a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2),..., but the n does not differ pixelwise through each pixel.
The most simple case would be having one image I1 and I have the parameters (a1, b1, c1), and the needed n can be calculated using a roots method or a minimizer:
def my_model(n, a, b, c, img=0):
    return a * n**2 + b * n + c - img

# load img1, a1, b1, c1 from a file
n = np.zeros_like(img1)
for i in range img1.shape[0]:
    for j in range img1.shape[1]:
        x0 = 1/3
        args = {
            "a": a1,
            "b": b1,
            "c": c1,
            "img": img1[i,j],
        }

        res = least_squares(my_model, x0, kwargs=args)
        n[i, j] = res.x[0]

Looping over each pixel takes quite a long time, and I have already tried to reduce the double for-loop using just one and module and integer division to calculate the indices i,j.
If I could make this faster, multiple images wouldn't be that hard to implement too, since I only have to provide an array to the parameters.
EDIT 2
I checked my derivation function again and it seems I had a bug in it, but it is fixed now (I tested it against data from Matlab). I implemented an additional flag in the original function and a wrapper:
def my_model(n, a, b, c, img=0, derivative=False):
    if derivative:
        return 2 * a * n + b
    return a * n**2 + b * n + c - img

def my_model_derivative(n, a, b, c):
    return my_model(n, a, b, c, derivative=True)

# load img1, a1, b1, c1 from a file
n = np.zeros_like(img1)
x0 = 1/3
for i in range img1.shape[0]:
    for j in range img1.shape[1]:
        args = {
            "a": a1,
            "b": b1,
            "c": c1,
            "img": img1[i,j],
        }

        res = least_squares(my_model, x0, my_model_derivative, kwargs=args)
        n[i, j] = res.x[0]
        x0 = res.x[0]

I know the wrapper isn't needed in this case, but my actual function is quite complicated and I would need to maintain duplicated code.
After fixing the issue, the performance hasn't improved much, if at all. I guess the largest bottleneck is the loop over the image.

Can you edit your question to show what code you tried to run? It's quite difficult to help otherwise. You might find How do I ask a good question? to be a helpful resource. Thanks!

"I am looping over all pixels with a for-loop and applying the model pixelwise." That is likely to be extremely slow. Vectorization might help.

"I also implemented the derivative values, since I heard it could be faster by providing the jacobian matrix, but to no avail." I'm surprised that doesn't help. Typically when no jacobian is provided, it must be estimated with numeric differentiation. If you had a 100px by 100px image, that would take 10,000 function evaluations to perform numeric differentiation. Unless the jacobian function is incredibly slow, it should be much faster than numeric differentiation.

what are the problems with NumbaMinpack? I have written cminpack_numba and minpack_numba which may not suffer from the same issues

@jakevdp I added two edits with an example function that I want to optimize and then how I created the derivative of that function. These are only examples, since the real code is quite complicated!

@NickODell The jacobian is as fast as the main function, so I am not sure how well that performs...

@Nin17 That sounds really promising! I will give it a look, but first I need to jit everything possible with numba and numba-scipy! Can I open an issue if I have questions on how to use the wrapped functions? I have never used minpack before.

Sure, there should be some examples and the tests that you can look at to see how to use them. You should start with lmdif/lmdif1 if you aren't supplying a Jacobian function or lmder/lmder1 if you are as these are what is used in scipy.optimize.leastsq

There are a couple of ways you could approach this problem.
One trick to speeding up a least_squares fit is to provide a starting value close to the actual root of the function.
If the pixels of your image are correlated with one another, one way to do this would be to take the n value you got from solving the previous least_squares problem, and supply that as x0 to the next call. I observed about a 10x speedup from this.
Another approach would be to try to find a faster way to compute f-1(x). There are various approaches you could use, but one way is to evaluate f(x) at a bunch of points, and fit a spline from f(x) to x.
This takes longer to fit the spline if you're just converting one pixel, but the advantage is that it saves time when doing many evaluations.
Here's an example. I took your code, and used it with the following image test pattern. (Save this image as grayscale.png in the same directory to test this.)
I then compared two methods: the pixel by pixel method, and fitting a spline to the function inverse. I found that the spline method was about 100x faster.
The spline method benefits from two things: it takes less computation to identify the inverse, and more of the calculation can be done in a vectorized fashion. This is about 100x faster.
import time
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy


img1 = np.asarray(Image.open("grayscale.png"))
# Extract first channel
img1 = img1[..., 0]
# load img1, a1, b1, c1 from a file
a1 = 1
b1 = 1
c1 = 1


def my_model(n, a, b, c, img=0):
    return a * n**2 + b * n + c - img


def pixelwise_convert(func, img):
    n = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        x0 = 1/3
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            args = {
                "a": a1,
                "b": b1,
                "c": c1,
                "img": img[i,j],
            }

            res = scipy.optimize.least_squares(func, x0, kwargs=args)
            n[i, j] = x0 = res.x[0]
    return n


def fit_spline_to_function_inverse(func, img, acc=1e-10):
    n_points = 10
    n_random_sample = 50
    spline_order = 3
    def inv_func(img_scalar, x0=0):
        args = {
            "a": a1,
            "b": b1,
            "c": c1,
            "img": img_scalar,
        }

        res = scipy.optimize.least_squares(func, x0, kwargs=args, xtol=acc, ftol=acc, gtol=acc)
        return res.x[0]
    while True:
        sample_start = inv_func(img.min())
        sample_end = inv_func(img.max())
        n_values = np.linspace(sample_start, sample_end, n_points)
        i_values = func(n_values, a1, b1, c1)
        ind = i_values.argsort()
        i_values = i_values[ind]
        n_values = n_values[ind]
        spline = scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline(i_values, n_values, k=spline_order)
        # Pick some random out of sample values to try
        random_input_values = np.random.choice(img.flatten(), size=n_random_sample)
        # Try both methods. Is spline with current number of points
        # accurate enough?
        err = []
        for val in random_input_values:
            interpolate_inverse = spline(val)
            optimize_inverse = inv_func(val, x0=interpolate_inverse)
            err.append(interpolate_inverse - optimize_inverse)
        accuracy_rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.array(err) ** 2))
        print(f"Fitting spline with {n_points} points, average error of {accuracy_rmse:.2g}")
        if accuracy_rmse < acc:
            break
        # Not accurate enough. Try with more points
        n_points = int(1.6 * n_points)
    return spline


def main():
    start = time.time()
    result1 = pixelwise_convert(my_model, img1)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Pixelwise method duration: {end - start:.2f}s")
    start = time.time()
    spline = fit_spline_to_function_inverse(my_model, img1)
    result2 = spline(img1)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Spline method duration: {end - start:.2f}s")
    print("Are the two methods close?", np.allclose(result1, result2))
    
main()

